# I want to add async await function to pull data from react-native firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm building a React Native app using Firebase. I use the following method (among others) in one of my components to get data from Firebase:

The problem is that sometimes the data is loaded as an empty dictionary (Object {}) and I can't switch to the pages that require authorization because all the information belonging to the user is not received. I don't know how to print

[image]

Comment: Please copy/paste your code as text.

Answer (score 0):

The [`on()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.Reference#on) method sets a listener that listens for data changes at the `users` db node. It is not an asynchronous method, therefore you don't need to use `async` in the encapsulating function.

if I correctly understand your question, you should use the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.Reference#get) method, which is asynchronous, as follows:

```
async function getData() {
    try {
        
        const snapshot = await firebase
        .database()
        .ref('users')
        .get();
        
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            // Check here the value of the snapshot with snapshot.val()
            // and act accordingly if it returns (Object {})
            
          } else {
            // ....
          }
        
        
    } catch (error) {
        // ...
    }
}
```